# Title bar not visible using ExtendViewIntoTitleBar=true in UWP app c#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

So I would like to customize the title bar of my UWP app as suggested here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar. I would like to use a custom `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView` and display that instead of the default title bar. So in my Xaml code I have:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Posta.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Posta"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <NavigationView x:Name="TopNavigationView" Header="Hello" PaneDisplayMode="Top" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0">
                <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="HomeItem" Content="Home" Icon="Home" ></NavigationViewItem>
                </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            </NavigationView>
        <WebView Source="https://website.com" Grid.Row="1" ></WebView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And in my C# code I added when initializing the page:

```
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    TopNavigationView.Height = coreTitleBar.Height; // check this height setting (because we sat it to auto in xaml)
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(TopNavigationView);
```

However, now my NavigationView is not visible when I launch the application and only the WebView is extended into the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [CoreApplicationViewTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar.LayoutMetricsChanged) to update the `TopNavigationView.Height` by `coreTitleBar.Height` like the document has shown in the demo code.

```
private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    UpdateTitleBarLayout(sender);
}

private void UpdateTitleBarLayout(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar)
{
    // Update title bar control size as needed to account for system size changes.
    TopNavigationView.Height = coreTitleBar.Height;
}
```

Comment: Hmm so following your suggestion I added a `coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;` when I initialize my page but now my NavigationView appears to be empty

Comment: It's because the `coreTitleBar.Height` is too small. This is not enough to display the contents of the NavigationView. If you set the height(e.g,TopNavigationView.Height=100), you will see it.